# Op-Ed or Editorial?

Tags: word-usage, semantics

I have a piece that is an opinion written by a columnist. If I only had the designation of an op-ed or of an editorial. What word better describes the piece?

An editorial is supposed to be written by a senior member of the staff or the published (according to wikipedia).

On the other than an op-ed. is "a piece typically published by newspapers, magazines, and the like which expresses the opinions of a named author usually affiliated with the publication's editorial board." (also wikipedia)

I think it's more akin to an op-ed. but I want some input.

Comment: Why not just call it a ***column**?* If someone tells me he writes a column in *The Times*, I don't suppose he's a *news* reporter - the usage is reserved for "opinion pieces".

Comment: If it is the opinion of the editor, or editorial board it is usually called an *editorial*. But in Britain it is often referred to as a *leading article* or *leader*. One speaks of a *Times Leader* or a *Guardian Leader*, and the people who write them as 'Leader writers*. People who write pieces which express opinion, but who are not members of the editorial board of a newspaper are usually called *columnists*. I have never heard of the term *op-ed*.

Comment: @WS2 has the correct answer for British English. We don't use 'op-ed' at all.

Comment: very interesting especially about the usage differentiation between American/English and British

Comment: @franklin Since the usage differs across languages, it would be great if you can mention the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for *op-ed*:

> **op-ed** *n, often cap O&E, often attrib* {short for *opposite editorial*} (1970) a page of special features usu. opposite the editorial page of a newspaper; *also* : a feature of such a page

In my original answer to this question, I was so sure that *op-ed* stood for "opinion/editorial" that I didn't bother to look it up—until almost 12 months later, when commenter Kyle pointed out that I was completely wrong about what the *op* part of the abbreviation stood for. (My heartfelt thanks to Kyle for identifying the correct meaning of *op-ed* and enabling me to escape further ignominy as the source of a demonstrably erroneous answer.)

In print newspapers in the United States, *op-ed*—which is indeed short for "opposite editorial"—refers to a page of content in the newspaper consisting of opinion columns that (traditionally) fill the right-hand page of a two-page spread in which the left-hand page is devoted (more or less) to institutional editorials.

The print *New York Times* offers an illustrative case in point. Six days a week (Monday through Saturday), about three-fifths of the left-hand page of the spread consists of unsigned editorials by *New York Times* editors, representing the institutional opinions of the newspaper, and about two-fifths of the page consists of letters to the editor from readers; the left-hand page as a whole is labeled "Editorials/Letters." The right-hand page of the same spread—which the New York Times labels "Op-Ed"—consists of opinion columns by staff columnists or by guest columnists. On Sundays, the *New York Times* expands its opinion & analysis offerings to an entire section, which it calls "Sunday Review"; but even in this case, the final spread of the section is a spread with "Editorials/Letters" on the left-hand page and "Op-Ed" on the right-hand page.

Many U.S. daily newspapers follow this same format, more or less, although most also include an editorial cartoon on the left-hand page (the *New York Times* doesn't set aside space for editorial cartoons—or comic strip cartoons either). But other U.S. dailies limit their combined editorial and op-ed content to a single page instead of offering a two-page spread. The *Oakland [California] Tribune*, for example, has a single right-hand page that it labels "Opinion" and populates with an institutional editorial, a large editorial cartoon, two or three letters to the editor, and—at the bottom of the page—what would normally be an op-ed piece from a syndicated columnist.

Herein lies the problem with applying nomenclature from a standard two-page spread of editorial and guest-opinion content to a one-page format. If a signed column written by a *New York Times* staff, syndicated, or guest columnist and appearing originally on that newspaper's op-ed page gets picked up by the *Oakland Tribune* and run at the bottom of its single-page "Opinion" section, does the column remain an "op-ed piece" or does it become an "editorial"?

To me, the fact that a column appears on a newspaper's (single) editorial page doesn't automatically make it an editorial, any more than the fact that one-page editorial sections tend to appear on the right-hand page of a layout (the traditional location of the op-ed page) makes everything on that page an op-ed. Instead, I think, an op-ed piece in the *New York Times* or *Washington Post* or *Wall Street Journal* or other newspaper that has a two-page spread of editorial and opinion content remains an op-ed piece when it reappears on the combined "opinion" page of a newspaper that devotes just one page to editorial and opinion content every day.

Under the conventions of current U.S. journalism, an article written and signed by a columnist is called an *op-ed piece* or an *opinion column*. It is not normally called an *editorial* because that designation, if used within the walls of the newspaper office itself, would invite confusion between unsigned pieces written to represent the newspaper's institutional voice ("editorials") and signed articles representing one columnist's opinions ("opinion pieces"). The same reasoning would lead me to call the OP's "opinion [piece] written by a columnist" an *op-ed column* and not an *editorial*.

---

***Final thoughts about 'op-ed'***

Murkiness about the exact meaning of *op-ed* goes back at least as far as 1971—just one year after (according to Merriam-Webster) the *New York Times* introduced the term *op-ed* to the world. From [*Time*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hhonAQAAIAAJ&q=%22editorials.+The+addition+was+%22&dq=%22editorials.+The+addition+was+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSsa_WjoPKAhUNxmMKHU89B6EQ6AEIHTAA) magazine, volume 97 (1971) [combined snippets]:

> The New York *Times* has no reputation for sudden innovation, so it came as something of a surprise when, last September, the paper introduced an "Op-Ed" page, journalist's jargon for an **opinion page opposite the editorials**. The addition was a notable change for the *Times*. Since then, it has not only become one of the closely watched and sought-after forums for comment in U.S. daily journalism, but probably the best Op-Ed page anywhere.
>
> The Op-Ed format was first popularized by Editor Herbert Bayard Swope on the Pulitzers' old New York *World* in the early 1920s. It is now used by many U.S. papers, which usually fill it with syndicated columns. At the *Times*, that particular page had for decades been the repository of the obituaries. To begin the new feature, the death notices were banished to the second section, making room for a dizzying diversity of views and opinions that perhaps only the Times, with its great prestige, could bring together. Regular Columnists James Reston, C.L. Sulzberger, Russell Baker, and Tom Wicker share the space with outside contributors, who differ widely in political philosophy  (from New Leftist Herbert Marcuse to Right Wing Libertarian Murray Rothbard) and in personality (from Burma's ascetic rebel U Nu to baseball's syntax-smashing Casey Stengel).

In this account in *Time*, readers may wrongly read the *op* in *op-ed* as referring to "opinion" or rightly read it as referring to "opposite": the reporter's wording accommodates both interpretations. A discussion of the term in Carl Gershman, "[The 'Times' Op-Ed Page: Both Ends Against the Middle](https://books.google.com/books?id=IJ8eAAAAMAAJ&q=%22op+ed%22&dq=%22op+ed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBpoe2koPKAhUBE2MKHWm8Cvg4FBDoAQglMAI)," in *Commentary*, volume 55 (1973) [combined snippets] is far clearer:

> In the past two-and-a-half years, the Op-Ed page of the New York *Times*—so-called because it appears opposite the editorial page—has become a powerful presence in American culture. Like the *Times* itself, it is an institution of national ...

One last complication involves the first-occurrence date of 1970 that the *Eleventh Collegiate* cites. Irving Bernstein, [*The Turbulent Years: A History of the American Worker, 1933-1941*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aaHaroUImGIC&pg=PA130&dq=%22op+ed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38Ij5k4PKAhUL8mMKHbdgDbE4HhDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22op%20ed%22&f=false) (1969) twice refers to what he calls the 1921 *New York World*'s "Op. Ed." page. Whether or not the *World* called the page hosting its columns "the Op. Ed. page" back in 1921, Bernstein appears to have done so in 1969, a year before the *New York Times* began calling its page of signed editorial columns *Op-Ed*.

Comment: "In U.S, English op-ed (short for "opinion and editorial")" -- This is not true. Op-ed is short for "opposite the editorial page."

Comment: @Kyle: You're right. I just checked Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary and found this entry for _op-ed_: "**op-ed** _n, often cap O&E, often attrib_ {short for _opposite editorial_} (1970) a page of special features usu. opposite the editorial page of a newspaper; _also_ : a feature of such a page." Thanks for pointing out my serious (and unfounded) error in identifying the "op" part of the abbreviation as referring to _opinion_ instead of to _opposite_. I will correct the mistake at once. Thanks again for the wake-up call.

Comment: @Kyle: I decided that the answer I originally submitted was too flawed in too many ways to bear scrutiny—so I rewrote the whole thing. Thanks again for letting me know about the blunder that I built my original answer around. I'm usually a lot more careful about checking and corroborating my assertions than I was in this case.